# Shortcode parsed incorrectly because of heredoc

Tags: shortcode

I have a post with something like this:

```
[code]
$foo = <<<EOT
  ....
EOT;
[/code]
```

It gets converted to this by `do_shortcodes_in_html_tags()`:

```
[code]
$foo = <<<EOT
  ....
EOT;
&#91;/code&#q3;
```

Therefore, the shortcode doesn't run. Is there a way to make this shortcode work correctly?

Answer (score 2):

A workaround might be:

```
[code]
$foo = &lt;&lt;&lt;EOT
  ....
EOT;
[/code]
```

where we change `<<<` to `&lt;&lt;&lt;`. We could do this automatically before `do_shortcode` filters the content and then replace it again afterwards.

I tested this version:

```
[code]
$foo = <<<EOT
....
EOT;<!---->
[/code]
```

and it seems to parse the shortocde's content correctly. But then we would need to remove the extra `<!---->` part, after `do_shortcode` has filtered the content. *This approach, with the HTML comment, would display the correct HTML source, but the rendering would be problematic, except within a `<textarea>`.*

**Peeking into the `/wp-includes/shortcodes.php` file**

The problem using an unclosed HTML tag, within the shortcode's content, seems to be that the `do_shortcodes_in_html_tags()` parser thinks `[/code]` is a part of it.

[This part](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/ba12f4e95fec5e132868c21c5944a246841da9f3/wp-includes/shortcodes.php#L386-L387) of `do_shortcodes_in_html_tags()` seems to influense this behavior:

```
// Looks like we found some crazy unfiltered HTML.  Skipping it for sanity.
$element = strtr( $element, $trans );
```

where `[/code]` is replaced to `&#91;/code&#93;`.

This happens just before the shortcode regex-replacements.

We would see `&#91;/code&#93;` from the output of `the_content()`, if [this part](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/ba12f4e95fec5e132868c21c5944a246841da9f3/wp-includes/shortcodes.php#L226):

```
$content = unescape_invalid_shortcodes( $content );
```

wouldn't run at the end of the `do_shortcode()` function.

So it's like we didn't close the shortcode.

**HTML Encoding The Code Blocks**

We could HTML encode the content of the code blocks with:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content )
{
    if( has_shortcode( $content, 'code' ) ) 
        $content = preg_replace_callback( 
            '#\[code\](.*?)\[/code\]#s', 
            'wpse_code_filter', 
            $content 
        );

    return $content;

}, 1 );
```

where our custom callback is defined as:

```
function wpse_code_filter( $matches )
{
    return esc_html( $matches[0] );
}
```

Note that there are still things to be sorted out like

- content filters within the core, e.g. the `wpautop` filter,
- content filters from 3rd party plugins
- shortcodes inside the codeblock,
- etc.

It's informative to look at plugins like [`SyntaxHighligther Evolved`](https://wordpress.org/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/) to see the what kind of workarounds would be needed. (I'm not related to that plugin).

**Alternatives**

Another approach is to move the code outside of the content editor and store it in e.g.

- custom fields,
- custom tables
- custom post type (e.g. stored as  excerpts).

For the latter case, this kind of shortcode comes to mind (PHP 7+):

```
add_shortcode( 'codeblock', function( Array $atts, String $content )
{
    // Setup default attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts( [ 'id' => 0 ], $atts, 'codeblock_shortcode' );

    // We only want to target the 'codeblock' post type
    if( empty( $atts['id'] ) || 'codeblock' !== get_post_type( $atts['id'] ) ) 
        return $content;

    // Pre wrapped and HTML escaped post-excerpt from the 'codeblock' post type
    return sprintf( 
            '<pre>%s</pre>',
            esc_html( 
                get_post_field(
                    'post_excerpt', 
                    $atts['id'], 
                    'raw' 
                )
            )
        );
} );
```

*This might need further testing and adjustments!*

Then we could refer to each codeblock with

```
[codeblock id="123"]
```

in the content editor.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I don't like this solution because it only works for exactly 3 consecutive `<`'s. I would prefer a generic solution, such as escaping `<`'s in shortcodes somehow. For now, I'm using CDATA and stripping CDATA from the shortcode content.

Comment: I updated the answer with an HTML escaping example and some  alternatives @LeoJiang

Answer (score 0):

### Shortcode With Hidden Payload

Another approach would be to pre-process the shortcode's content, by temporarily removing it, before e.g. the `wpautop()` and `do_shortcode()` act on it and then replacing it again afterwards.

*I'm sure this kind of approach has been implemented in various ways before, but I played with it in this way:*

### Example

Here's an example of the pre-processing:

```
[code lang="php"]
$foo = <<<EOT
  ....
EOT;
[/code]
```

This code block would be replaced with:

```
[code lang="php"]code_b6a7d410d48883693b6714b68a4eee0a[/code]
```

where the reference number could be `md5` of the code block's content.

The processing of `do_shortcode()` and `wpautop()` should now not be a problem for the content of our code block.

Our shortcode will then output the code block corresponding to the reference number.

### Basic implementation

The basic setup would be registering the shortcode and the early pre-processing filter:

```
add_shortcode( $tag, [ $this, 'shortcode' ] );
add_filter( 'the_content', [ $this, 'filter_before' ], 0 );
```

The shortcode is defined as:

```
public function shortcode( $atts, $content )
{
    // Default attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts( ['lang' => 'php'], $atts, 'codeblock_shortcode' );

    // Restore the code block's content, HTML escaped it and pre-wrap it
    return sprintf( 
        '<pre lang="%s">%s</pre>',
        esc_attr( $atts['lang'] ),
        esc_html( $this->filter_after( $content ) ) 
    );
}
```

where the code blocks are hidden with a `filter_before()` method and restored with a `filter_after()` method. Then HTML escaped and finally wrapped in a `<pre>` tag.

In this kind of a problem, it's handy to use `preg_replace` with a callback.

### Demo Plugin

Here's a demo plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Simple Code Block
 * Description: Support for the [code] shortcode to display code snippets.
 * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/233740/26350
 * Author:      birgire
 * Version:     1.0.0
 */

namespace WPSE\SimpleCodeBlock;

add_action( 'init', function()
{
    $o = new CodeBlock;
    $o->init( $tag = 'code' );
} );


class CodeBlock
{
    private $blocks;
    private $tag;

    public function init( $tag )
    {           
        if( ! shortcode_exists( $tag ) && preg_match( '#^[a-z]+$#', $tag ) )
        {
            $this->tag = $tag;
            $this->blocks = [];

            add_shortcode( $tag, [ $this, 'shortcode' ] );
            add_filter( 'the_content', [ $this, 'filter_before' ], 0 );
        }
    }

    public function filter_before( $content )
    {
        if( $this->has_code_block( $content ) )
        {
            $tag = preg_quote( $this->tag );

            $pattern = "#(\[{$tag}(\s+[^\]]+)?\])(.*?)(\[\/{$tag}\])#s";
            $content = preg_replace_callback( 
                $pattern, 
                [ $this, 'regex_before' ], 
                $content 
            );

        }
        return $content;
    }

    public function filter_after( $content ) 
    {
        if( $this->has_code_key( $content ) )
        {
            $tag = preg_quote( $this->tag );
            $pattern = "#{$tag}\_[a-z0-9]{32}#"; 
            $content = preg_replace_callback(
                $pattern,
                [ $this, 'regex_after' ], 
                $content 
            );
        }       
        return $content;
    }

    public function regex_before ( Array $matches )  
    {               
        // Nothing to do 
        if( 5 !== count( $matches ) )
            return;

        // Generate a key from the code block's content
        $key = $this->tag . '_' . md5( $matches[3] );

        // Temporarily store the code block
        $this->blocks[$key] = $matches[3];  

        // Return this form [code ...]code_b6a7d410d48883693b6714b68a4eee0a[/code]
        return $matches[1] . $key . $matches[4];
    }

    public function regex_after( Array $matches )
    {   
        $key = $matches[0];

        // Restore the code block's content
        if( isset( $this->blocks[$key] ) )
            return $this->blocks[$key];

        return;     
    }

    public function shortcode( $atts = [], $content = '' )
    {
        // Default attributes
        $atts = shortcode_atts( ['lang' => 'php'], $atts, 'codeblock_shortcode' );

        // Restore the code block's content, HTML escaped it and pre-wrap it
        return sprintf( 
            '<pre lang="%s">%s</pre>',
            esc_attr( $atts['lang'] ),
            esc_html( $this->filter_after( $content ) ) 
        );
    }

    private function has_code_key( $content )
    {
        return false !== strpos( $content, $this->tag . '_' );
    }

    private function has_code_block( $content )
    {
        return false !== strpos( $content, '[' . $this->tag );
    }

} // end class
```

It's also possible to adjust this slightly, so that `[code]` isn't defined as a shortcode and restore the code block's content at the priority of `PHP_INT_MAX` within the `the_content` filter.